# How to Select Distinct Name based on LastCreatedDate in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have sample table with columns:

```
ID(guid)                                 Name        CreatedDate

B27EB95B-B219-46BD-9E72-A378B3E7FED0    A       2005-11-20 22:49:46.000
33D43825-918D-4DC0-874A-53670563EA03    A       2009-10-03 10:34:00.000
28F26DA6-B144-4C0C-AC2F-4DDD2D74357E    B       2011-03-23 08:08:39.000
1491D95F-BA58-41EE-8982-B713DE9DECD7    C       2006-01-18 14:53:12.000
FD25C05D-0C1A-4314-BCA7-F4F33B0E890D    C       2006-10-05 14:25:58.000
F4256300-CAA6-4E80-8D1B-B89273274088    D       2008-03-12 08:56:32.000
```

That Supposed to be my OledbDatasource on SSIS.

Now problem is i need to get the distinct Name having the last createdDate and its Id in sql.

This is the output result:

```
ID(guid)                                 Name        CreatedDate

33D43825-918D-4DC0-874A-53670563EA03    A       2009-10-03 10:34:00.000
28F26DA6-B144-4C0C-AC2F-4DDD2D74357E    B       2011-03-23 08:08:39.000
047ED9C3-DF92-45D5-B295-EE52184116FB    C           2006-10-05 14:23:40.000
F4256300-CAA6-4E80-8D1B-B89273274088    D       2008-03-12 08:56:32.000
```

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Name, CreatedDate
FROM table JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(CreatedDate) CreatedDate, Name FROM table GROUP BY Name) max_date
USING (Name, CreatedDate)
```

(Change table to the actual name of the table.)

For SQLServer do:

```
SELECT table.ID, table.Name, table.CreatedDate
FROM table JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(CreatedDate) CreatedDate, Name FROM table GROUP BY Name) max_date
ON table.Name = max_date.name AND table.CreatedDate = max_date.CreatedDate
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my instance of SQL Server. What have you tested it on?

Comment: It's generic SQL, I didn't test it on SQL Server. Does SQL Server support joining to a sub-query?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `JOIN...USING`.

Comment: Even if it did, won't this get you the "MAX(CreatedDate)" per *ID* rather than Name? That'll just get you every record.

Comment: @matt-hamilton oops! Thanks, I've edited it. This query assumes the CreatedDate is unique per name, otherwise you may have an ambiguous result.

Comment: You'll still have an issue where there is more than one row per name with the same CreatedDate, but the question didn't specify what to do in that case. Your query will return all the rows with the same date, while mine and @Andriy's will only return one per name.

Comment: @matt-hamilton That is true. But how do you pick the "MAX" date if they are both the same? Does it pick an id randomly?

Comment: @Ariel: [Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx) (Re "change USING to ON").

Answer (score 2):

If you are on SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use [ranking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) and a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    ID, Name, CreatedDate,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Name,
  CreatedDate
FROM ranked
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: +1 - this is actually more efficient than my CROSS APPLY solution. I'll leave my answer here for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
SELECT myTable.Id, myTable.Name, myTable.CreatedDate
FROM table as myTable
INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, MAX(CreatedDate) AS MaxDate FROM table GROUP BY Name) 
    AS MaxRecord ON MaxRecord.Name = myTable.Name 
                AND MaxRecord.MaxDate= myTable.CreatedDate
```

Comment: I use a more complex version of this all the time and it works a treat

Comment: Sorry, but how does it differ from @Ariel's solution?

Comment: It doesn't.. That part of his response wasn't there when I started writing my response. He only had the Join Using method which isn't supported by sql server as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the result you want on SQL Server:

```
select distinct x.ID, x.Name, x.CreatedDate
from table t
    cross apply (
        select top 1 ID, Name, CreatedDate
        from table t1 
        where t1.Name = t.Name
        order by CreatedDate desc
    ) x
order by x.Name;
```